# WP_Query breaks when searching custom field with phrase containing a space

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am filtering a Wordpress CPT based on what the user selects from a list of custom fields. It works fine when the custom field contains no space but when it contains a space it returns nothing.

I've tried every possible compare option ("LIKE", "IN", etc.).

The select list is created dynamically and outputs the following.

```
<form class="cd-new-brews-table-filter" method="GET">
  <select id="beer-style" name="beer-style">
    <option value="0">Any Style</option>
    <option value="Cider">Cider</option>
    <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
    <option value="Lager">Lager</option>
    <option value="Pale Ale">Pale Ale</option>
    <option value="Pilsner">Pilsner</option>
    <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
    <option value="Stout">Stout</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="submit-filter" class="submit button" value="Filter" />
</form>
```

The selected value is sent to a script for processing and loading the content on the page...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('body').on('click','#submit-filter',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var beer_style = $('#beer-style').val();
    console.log(beer_style + ' filter submitted.');
    $( "#cd_keg_sales_table" ).html('<img class="ajax-loader" src="../wp-content/themes/Divi-child/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    $( "#cd_keg_sales_table" ).load( "../wp-content/themes/Divi-child/ajax/default.php?beer-style=" + beer_style, function() {
        console.log('jQ load() completed.');
    });
});
```

});

default.php is fired on the server and returns to the browser successfully every time. Unless the selected option contains a space like "Pale Ale".

```
$filters = array();

$beer_style_filter = $_GET['beer-style'];

if ( isset($beer_style_filter) && $beer_style_filter != '0' ) {
    array_push($filters, array('key' => 'beer_style','value' => $beer_style_filter,'compare' => '='));
}

$keg_sales_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'beer',
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'beer_hide_in_keg_sales',
                'value' => '"yes"',
                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
            ),
            $filters,
        ),

    );

$query_keg_sales = new WP_Query( $keg_sales_args );
```

I expect results when searching "Pale Ale" but get nothing at all back from the server when the $beer_style_filter variable contains a space and is handled by array_push(). I have no idea what I might be overlooking here.

Answer (score 1):

If custom value contain space just replace the space with underscore

```
<option value="Pale_Ale">Pale Ale</option>
```

After that In php replace the underscore with space..
Just copy and paste the below code.

```
filters = array();
$beer_style_filter = $_GET['beer-style'];
$beer_style_filter = str_replace('_',' ',$beer_style_filter);
 if ( isset($beer_style_filter) && $beer_style_filter != '0' ) { 
       array_push($filters, array('key' => 'beer_style','value' => "$beer_style_filter",
'compare' => '=')); 
       } 
      $keg_sales_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
           'post_type' => 'beer',
           'orderby' => 'title', 
           'order' => 'ASC', 
          'meta_query' => array( 
          'relation' => 'AND', array( 
          'key' => 'beer_hide_in_keg_sales', 
          'value' => '"yes"', 
          'compare' => 'NOT LIKE' ), $filters, ), 
     );
     $query_keg_sales = new WP_Query( $keg_sales_args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array into `$filters` array but you need only an array and not an array of array.

try this code

```
$filters = array();

$beer_style_filter = $_GET['beer-style'];

if ( isset($beer_style_filter) && $beer_style_filter != '0' ) {
    $filters = array(
        'key' => 'beer_style',
        'value' => $beer_style_filter,
        'compare' => '='
    );
}
$keg_sales_args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'beer',
        'orderby'           => 'title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'beer_hide_in_keg_sales',
                'value' => '"yes"',
                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
            ),
            $filters,
        ),

    );
$query_keg_sales = new WP_Query( $keg_sales_args );
```